# Python & Django: Cannot Retrieve Defaults From 2 Layer Deep Foreign Key Relationship

Tags: python, django

I found this trick, which might be a hack, to set default values when the field is a foreign key to another database:

```
class House(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return name

    @classmethod
    def get_default(cls):
        return cls.objects.filter(address="5360 Wallaby Lane").first().pk

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["name"]
```

When constructing another class that references this field, we can set a default as follows:

```
class Neighborhood(models.Model):
    favourite_house = models.ForeignKey("civilization.House", on_delete=models.PROTECT, default=House.get_default())
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

    @classmethod
    def get_default(cls):
        return cls.objects.filter(name="Upper Snootington").first().pk
```

This works fine. As long as this function referencing a second layer isn't called by another default field for a table, Django doesn't complain. Once I tie this in as a default to another model, however:

```
class City(models.Model):
    favourite_neighborhood = models.ForeignKey("civilization.Neighborhood", on_delete=models.PROTECT, default=Neighborhood.get_default())
```

Django throws exceptions "django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.". It seems this is pretty specific to that second layer of default retrieval. The best I can surmise is that Django is trying to interact with the models while it builds the models with that second layer referencing another model.

Something tells me this is a hack and there's a better way...

```
Error Stack Trace:
Traceback (most recent call last):
2022-10-04T19:47:25.097693165Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 973, in _bootstrap_inner
2022-10-04T19:47:25.097697202Z     self.run()
2022-10-04T19:47:25.097700239Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 910, in run
2022-10-04T19:47:25.097724934Z     self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
2022-10-04T19:47:25.097732858Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
2022-10-04T19:47:25.097736509Z     fn(*args, **kwargs)
2022-10-04T19:47:25.097739522Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 110, in inner_run
2022-10-04T19:47:25.097742666Z     autoreload.raise_last_exception()
2022-10-04T19:47:25.097745656Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception
2022-10-04T19:47:25.097748771Z     raise _exception[1]
2022-10-04T19:47:25.097751654Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
2022-10-04T19:47:25.097754680Z     autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
2022-10-04T19:47:25.097757640Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
2022-10-04T19:47:25.097760614Z     fn(*args, **kwargs)
2022-10-04T19:47:25.097763440Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
2022-10-04T19:47:25.097766409Z     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
2022-10-04T19:47:25.097769265Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
2022-10-04T19:47:25.097772386Z     app_config.import_models()
2022-10-04T19:47:25.097775245Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 301, in import_models
2022-10-04T19:47:25.097814770Z     self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
2022-10-04T19:47:25.097822684Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2022-10-04T19:47:25.097827905Z     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2022-10-04T19:47:25.097833111Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
2022-10-04T19:47:25.101634487Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
2022-10-04T19:47:25.103934434Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2022-10-04T19:47:25.105839169Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
2022-10-04T19:47:25.107814611Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
2022-10-04T19:47:25.109409635Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
2022-10-04T19:47:25.111132100Z   File "/code/civilization/models.py", line 102, in <module>
2022-10-04T19:47:25.112666303Z     class Neighborhood(models.Model):
2022-10-04T19:47:25.112769078Z   File "/code/civilization/models.py", line 105, in City
2022-10-04T19:47:25.114428690Z     on_delete=models.PROTECT, default= get_default_neighborhood())
2022-10-04T19:47:25.114479112Z   File "/code/civilization/models.py", line 37, in get_default_neighborhood
2022-10-04T19:47:25.115610331Z     return Neighborhood.get_default()
2022-10-04T19:47:25.115733686Z   File "/code/civilization/models.py", line 29, in get_default
2022-10-04T19:47:25.116830129Z     return cls.objects.filter(address="5360 Wallaby Lane").first().pk
2022-10-04T19:47:25.116868823Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 674, in first
2022-10-04T19:47:25.119852074Z     for obj in (self if self.ordered else self.order_by('pk'))[:1]:
2022-10-04T19:47:25.119907893Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 280, in __iter__
2022-10-04T19:47:25.119917143Z     self._fetch_all()
2022-10-04T19:47:25.119920693Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1324, in _fetch_all
2022-10-04T19:47:25.119923803Z     self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
2022-10-04T19:47:25.119926782Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 51, in __iter__
2022-10-04T19:47:25.119931046Z     results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
2022-10-04T19:47:25.119935039Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1162, in execute_sql
2022-10-04T19:47:25.119938474Z     sql, params = self.as_sql()
2022-10-04T19:47:25.119941476Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 513, in as_sql
2022-10-04T19:47:25.119957520Z     extra_select, order_by, group_by = self.pre_sql_setup()
2022-10-04T19:47:25.119960883Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 56, in pre_sql_setup
2022-10-04T19:47:25.119963826Z     order_by = self.get_order_by()
2022-10-04T19:47:25.119966609Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 356, in get_order_by
2022-10-04T19:47:25.119969517Z     order_by.extend(self.find_ordering_name(
2022-10-04T19:47:25.119972298Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 740, in find_ordering_name
2022-10-04T19:47:25.119975219Z     field, targets, alias, joins, path, opts, transform_function = self._setup_joins(pieces, opts, alias)
2022-10-04T19:47:25.119978235Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 780, in _setup_joins
2022-10-04T19:47:25.119981145Z     field, targets, opts, joins, path, transform_function = self.query.setup_joins(pieces, opts, alias)
2022-10-04T19:47:25.119984116Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1648, in setup_joins
2022-10-04T19:47:25.120132662Z     path, final_field, targets, rest = self.names_to_path(
2022-10-04T19:47:25.120632399Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1539, in names_to_path
2022-10-04T19:47:25.121907397Z     if field.is_relation and not field.related_model:
2022-10-04T19:47:25.122421805Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
2022-10-04T19:47:25.123109833Z     res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
2022-10-04T19:47:25.123140347Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 95, in related_model
2022-10-04T19:47:25.123568285Z     apps.check_models_ready()
2022-10-04T19:47:25.123651924Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 141, in check_models_ready
2022-10-04T19:47:25.124090201Z     raise AppRegistryNotReady("Models aren't loaded yet.")
2022-10-04T19:47:25.124122833Z django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.
```

Comment: Put `Neighborhood.get_default()` in a function and reference to it with the `default` parameter.

Comment: I did this by creating a global namespaced function:
def get_default_neighborhood():
    return Neighborhood.get_default()

This causes the same issue.